# Serial connection to Intel Galileo on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port, intel-galileo

How do I connect to a galileo on the serial cable in ubuntu?

I've installed putty and set the baud rate to 115200. How to I know what port the board is on? Is there a command? is it /dev/ttys0?

Thanks
C

Answer (score 1):

Galileo 1 and 2 are have bit different serial cables. These instructions are for Galileo 2 with FTDI cable (connected to USB on the computer side).

If you are using Ubuntu, there should be no need for Putty. GNU screen does a good job for a command line terminal. You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

After that you can use screen to access the serial port:

```
sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200,-ixoff,ixon
```

Now booting up the Galileo device should get you to the serial console.